# How to reuse a pattern rule for the same target in (GNU) make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am automating a pipeline in `make` that consists of multiple operations that can be chained together.
Which operation was applied is indicated in the filename.
Sometimes I have to re-run the same operation within the same command chain to get a certain target, e.g. `make input.filtered.sorted.updated.sorted` should result in the following output files: `input.filtered`, `input.filtered.sorted`, `input.filtered.sorted.updated` and `input.filtered.sorted.updated.sorted`.
However, this seems not possible in one go.

Consider the following dummy implementation:

```sh
# just some dummy commands
save=and writing the result to $@
filter=@echo filtering $< accoring to some critera $(save)
sort=@echo sorting $< according to some criteria $(save)
update=@echo updating some values of $< according to $(word 2,$^) $(save)

# assume these input files exist
.PHONY : input update_table

# keep all intermediate files
.SECONDARY :

# this is what I would like to build
desired_target : input.filtered.sorted.updated.sorted

# this is what I can build
possible_target : input.filtered.sorted.updated

# just some dummy rules
%.filtered : % ; $(filter)
%.sorted : % ; $(sort)
%.updated : % update_table ; $(update)
```

Running `make` (i.e `make desired_target`) result in the following error:

```
make: \*** No rule to make target `input.filtered.sorted.updated.sorted', needed by `desired_target'.  Stop.
```

However, `make possible_target` works fine:

```
filtering input accoring to some critera and writing the result to input.filtered
sorting input.filtered according to some criteria and writing the result to input.filtered.sorted
updating some values of input.filtered.sorted according to update_table and writing the result to input.filtered.sorted.updated
```

Interestingly, running `touch input.filtered.sorted.updated && make` works as expected:

```
filtering input accoring to some critera and writing the result to input.filtered
sorting input.filtered according to some criteria and writing the result to input.filtered.sorted
updating some values of input.filtered.sorted according to update_table and writing the result to input.filtered.sorted.updated
sorting input.filtered.sorted.updated according to some criteria and writing the result to input.filtered.sorted.sorted.updated.sorted
```

How can I get `make` to run without the need of `touch`ing intermediate targets beforehand?

**Addendum:**

In case this was not clear from the previous examples, `make possible_target && make [desired_target]` works fine. So I want to get rid of the first call using `make`s dependecy tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [make manual - 10.4 Chains of Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules)

> No single implicit rule can appear more than once in a chain. This
>   means that make will not even consider such a ridiculous thing as
>   making foo from foo.o.o by running the linker twice. This constraint
>   has the added benefit of preventing any infinite loop in the search
>   for an implicit rule chain.

So, for me, the only way to do this is to create an *intermediate* rule like `possible_target` and to add it as a dependency of the `desired_target`.

```
desired_target : possible_target
```

Comment: Thx, I also tought this was due to `make` not looping on rules, but I was hoping there was some magic hidden param to increase the level of these kinds of paths to the dependency-tree. So apparently it's considered a feature and I have to live with it. Your solution to make the target depend on the intermediate seems to be the best way. Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a patch against 3.82](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?30381) which adds a `-M` option that allows using the same rule multiple times.

I use this for a particular Makefile that contains over 100 of the sort of rules you have here.

Let me know if you use it or if you want it adapted.